# Python multithreading/multiprocessing & limiting CPU core affinity

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, affinity

In Python, you can create new threads and processes to run a given task with `multiprocessing.Pool`, `multiprocessing.ThreadPool`, `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, and `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`.

By default, those threads/processes run with the same CPU core affinity as it's parent process, which is all cores/threads available.

On Linux/Unix systems, it is possible to change the CPU core affinity using `os.sched_setaffinity(pid, mask)`. The issue is the fact that this is limited to just some Linux/Unix systems.

There is the `psutil` python library that exposes the ability to set CPU core affinity with the `psutil.Process().cpu_affinity(CPUS)` where `CPUS` is a list of integers identifying which CPU cores/threads should be used by the process, starting at 0.

The issue is that generally the OS CPU scheduler can handle picking and choosing which core/thread should be utilized for a given process, rather than having an end user decide what CPU cores/threads to utilize.

The question I have is if it's possible to create the thread/process pools and limit each instance to using X number of CPU cores/threads, but not limit their exact core affinity?

For example, if I have PC with 16 cores and want to create 4 processes, I can create a `multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)` object. Now if I wanted each of those 4 children to be limited to only using 2 CPU cores each, I would have to use `psutil` to preemptively choose 2 CPU cores and assign them to that one process, reoving those 2 CPU cores from the available list of CPU cores, and repeat the process for all 4 processes.

But this would not be ideal, as what if I gave one process the two weakest cores in the system? Or if those 2 cores were further apart physically (such has the case of modern multi-chiplet AMD Ryzen CPU's or dual CPU socket systems).

I would want to let the OS schedule 2 cores for each process automatically and juggle them as it sees fit, rather than have to manually set and unset the CPU cores for each process.

Is there a way this can be done in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I had a similar need, so  I wrote a CPUResourceManager class to keep track of what cores I had assigned to a process.  Here you would call the
`get_processors` method to get a list of cores you are going to use.  You set the core affinity using PSUTIL as you are already doing.  When your process is done, return the cores using the `free_processors` method.

```
from typing import NamedTuple
from enum import Enum


class CPUResponse(NamedTuple):
    """
    This is the response when the CPUResourceManager is asked for some cores.
    """
    success: bool     # whether or not there are enough cores available
    processors: list  # the list of processors to be used by the process


class ProcState(Enum):
    """
    Represents the state of a processor core.  This is only 
    represents what we are having the cores do.  Not what other unrelated
    processes on the machine are doing
    """
    idle = 0
    busy = 1


class CPUResourceManager:
    def __init__(self, cpu_count=max(cpu_count() - 2, 1)) -> None:

        self.cpu_count = cpu_count

        self.processors = {i: ProcState.idle for i in range(self.cpu_count)}

    def cpu_avalaible_count(self):
        available = [
            p for p, state in self.processors.items() if state == ProcState.idle
        ]
        return len(available)

    def get_processors(self, count=1):
        """Get some available cores"""
        available = [
            p for p, state in self.processors.items() if state == ProcState.idle
        ]

        if len(available) >= count:
            cpus = available[:count]
            for p in cpus:
                self.processors[p] = ProcState.busy
            return CPUResponse(True, available[:count])
        else:
            return CPUResponse(False, [])

    def free_processors(self, processors: list):
        """return the cores when you are done"""
        for p in processors:
            if p in self.processors:
                self.processors[p] = ProcState.idle
            else:
                # manager was likely resized and this processor
                # should no longer be considered available
                pass
```