# How to set visible CPUs for (python) programs in Linux？

Tags: python, linux, cpu

When running (python) programs, I can use below code to set it only using No.1 and No.2 GPU:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1,2 python xxx.py
```

**So How can I set CPU devices for this same (python) program? Something like:**

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1,2 CPU_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0-10 python xxx.py
```

---

**Why I need this?**

I have a server which has multi cpus and gpus. The gpus are divided as needed by multi user using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1`. But the cpus are not.  So one user's program can take too much cpu power, slowing down other users.

I need some ways to divide the cpu as needed.

Comment: Python by itself can currently only use a single CPU because of the GIL. This is possibly going to be changed in a future Python version, but for the time being, that's how it is. If you want to run on multiple CPUs, maybe try the experimental Python fork which removes the GIL.

Comment: If your actual question is "how can I make it run on CPU 3 only" maybe check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69872036/how-to-assign-cpu-affinity-for-python-3-subprocess and perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69095641/python-multithreading-multiprocessing-limiting-cpu-core-affinity

Comment: @tripleee Sir, I have edited my question. I need to devide the cpu cores to multi user as needed. Because I notice that one user's program can occupy too much cpu power and slow down other users.

Comment: The first comment still stands; Python has `multiprocessing` for running mutiple processes, which allow you to run code on multiple CPUs, but a single script simply cannot run in more than one process.

Comment: I need something simpler, as simple as setting some envirionment viriables so I can run any program through the command line while indicating which cpus it should use. Is this possible?

Comment: No. Again, see my previous comments. Goto 10.

Comment: Note that `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` only works because the nVidia tools related to that know to look for it. There's no equivalent environment variable for the OS.